# vue-cli-service build: compiled code throw error "SyntaxError: 30" on execute

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

I've a *vue application with **js/ts mix***.

After running command `vue-cli-service build` the **compiled (prod-)code in browser (Chrome) returns multiple errors** with rare messages by `runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:226`:

```
SyntaxError: 30 (at compiler-core.esm-bundler.js:12:17)
    at bl (compiler-core.esm-bundler.js:12:17)
    at Nd (compiler-core.esm-bundler.js:3404:11)
    at Array.<anonymous> (compiler-core.esm-bundler.js:3603:44)
    at H_ (compiler-core.esm-bundler.js:2014:13)
    at F_ (compiler-core.esm-bundler.js:1966:5)
    at H_ (compiler-core.esm-bundler.js:2008:7)
    at F_ (compiler-core.esm-bundler.js:1966:5)
    at H_ (compiler-core.esm-bundler.js:2008:7)
    at z_ (compiler-core.esm-bundler.js:1900:3)
    at uh (compiler-core.esm-bundler.js:4678:3)
...
```

All requests are working, but the **page keeps blank**.

At the develop environment anything works without errors.

Here the package.json:

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "vue-running-with-webpack",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "docs": "jsdoc -d docs -c -r src --verbose",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit test/unit/**/*.spec.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.10.0",
    "@ui5/webcomponents": "^1.17.0",
    "@ui5/webcomponents-fiori": "^1.19.0",
    "@ui5/webcomponents-icons": "^1.19.0",
    "@ui5/webcomponents-icons-business-suite": "^1.17.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.3.4",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.4.1",
    "chai": "^4.3.10",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.7.1",
    "html-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "jsdoc": "^4.0.2",
    "jsdoc-vuejs": "^4.0.0",
    "odata": "^2.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.67.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.5.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.4",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}
```

Questions:

- **How to debug** the SyntaxError? (the message is not very usefull)
- Is the mix js/ts a problem?

Comment: You aren't in a very good situation as it's specific to your project setup and code, and yes, debugging info is lacking and requires you to dig into compiler source and probably debug it. Probably enabling building with "dev" env (not the same thing as dev server with npm serve) would make it more verbose, you can see this in createCompilerError source. Currently it looks like syntax problem with v-if https://unpkg.com/browse/@vue/compiler-core@3.3.8/dist/compiler-core.esm-bundler.js#L2845 , it's unknown why it didn't occur to you when you ran in dev server

Comment: You could start with double checking v-else-if sections in your code